# Need parse a complex array on NgFor

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I had this data structure:

[image]

I need acces the typo prop of each object that is inside of the array, acctualy I had this estructure on Ionic 2:

```
  <ion-item-group *ngFor="let data of contraCheque">
      <ion-item-divider color="light">{{ data[0].competencia }}</ion-item-divider> <!-- imprime o dado correto -->
      <ion-item (click)="consultarCheque(data)">{{ data }}</ion-item> <!-- imprime todos os objetos de cada array -->
      <ion-item (click)="consultarCheque(data)">{{ data[0].tipo }}</ion-item> <!-- imprime apenas a primeira prop de cada array -->
  </ion-item-group>
```

if I use the index to try print each prop of each type its print nothing (see image below)
and I think that the logic is wrong:

```
 <ion-item-group *ngFor="let data of contraCheque; index as i">
      <ion-item-divider color="light">{{ data[0].competencia }}</ion-item-divider>
      <ion-item (click)="consultarCheque(data)">{{ data[i].tipo }}</ion-item> 
  </ion-item-group>
```

I need to do the process below inside of my `*ngFor` is that possible? 
If not, please help me.

```
  const dadosContraCheque = [[{"tipo":"Complementar","id_folha":"24015","competencia":"03\/2017"}],[{"tipo":"Mensal","id_folha":"23855","competencia":"02\/2017"},{"tipo":"Sodexo","id_folha":"24075","competencia":"02\/2017"}],[{"tipo":"Mensal","id_folha":"23376","competencia":"01\/2017"},{"tipo":"Sodexo","id_folha":"23755","competencia":"01\/2017"}],[{"tipo":"13\u00ba Salari","id_folha":"22415","competencia":"12\/2016"},{"tipo":"Complementar","id_folha":"22535","competencia":"12\/2016"},{"tipo":"Mensal","id_folha":"22655","competencia":"12\/2016"},{"tipo":"Complemento","id_folha":"22675","competencia":"12\/2016"},{"tipo":"Sodexo","id_folha":"23015","competencia":"12\/2016"}],[{"tipo":"1\u00aa Parcela do 13\u00ba Salar","id_folha":"21798","competencia":"11\/2016"},{"tipo":"Mensal","id_folha":"21975","competencia":"11\/2016"},{"tipo":"Sodexo","id_folha":"22555","competencia":"11\/2016"}],[{"tipo":"Mensal","id_folha":"21295","competencia":"10\/2016"},{"tipo":"Sodexo","id_folha":"21755","competencia":"10\/2016"}],[{"tipo":"Mensal","id_folha":"21054","competencia":"09\/2016"},{"tipo":"Sodexo","id_folha":"21375","competencia":"09\/2016"}]]
  const tipo = dadosContraCheque.map(array => array.map(objeto => objeto.tipo) )
  console.log(tipo)
```

Comment: Do not paste pictures of code or links to pictures of code. Put the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are having array inside array so you should be using as below

```
  <ion-item-group *ngFor="let data of contraCheque[0]">
      <ion-item-divider color="light">{{ data[0].competencia }}</ion-item-divider> <!-- imprime o dado correto -->
      <ion-item (click)="consultarCheque(data)">{{ data |json }}</ion-item> <!-- will print array as json--> 
      <ion-item (click)="consultarCheque(data)">{{ data.tipo }}</ion-item> <!-- imprime apenas a primeira prop de cada array -->
  </ion-item-group>
```

Comment: This way is not working. It's print [this](http://image.prntscr.com/image/99403f95e7064e8f934633ea71d9bd25.png)

Answer (score 0):

this worked:

```
  <ion-item-group *ngFor="let data of contraCheque">
      <ion-item-divider color="light">{{ data[0].competencia }}</ion-item-divider>
      <span *ngFor="let d of data" >
        <ion-item (click)="consultarCheque(data)">{{ d.tipo }}</ion-item>
      </span>
  </ion-item-group>
```